# How to Export the listview to Excel much more faster?

Tags: vb.net, export-to-excel

I have this code for Exporting from listview to Excel but it is too slow when saving it is there a way to make it much more faster ?

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim bkWorkBook As Workbook
Dim shWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

    objExcel = New Excel.Application
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    bkWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add

    shWorkSheet = CType(bkWorkBook.ActiveSheet, Worksheet)
    shWorkSheet.Name = "ExportedFromListView"

    For i = 0 To Me.lvLogs.Columns.Count - 1
        shWorkSheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = Me.lvLogs.Columns(i).Text
    Next

    For i = 0 To Me.lvLogs.Items.Count - 1
       For j = 0 To Me.lvLogs.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
           shWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Me.lvLogs.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
       Next
    Next
        bkWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\SGTSI\Excel Attendance\biodata1.xlsx")
        bkWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\SGTSI\Attendance\SPA-" & DateTime.Now.ToString("y"-attendance.xlsx")

        bkWorkBook.Close()
```

Comment: What exactly is too slow? Do you mean that your application wait or hangs until this process finishes or what ?

Comment: First create an object array and then write the array to an excel range in a single line. Very fast this way.

Comment: Not using Excel Interop might be a good start!